# How to obtain Duplicate entries from DB, instead of just once?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, mysqli

I am pulling info about items from a database.

Each different item gets its own index number:

`$product[$x]`

If I list the item twice (See `banana` in code), Only one index number will be created.

How can I get an index number to be created for each item, independent of whether that item was already called?

```
<?php
include 'connect.php'; //

// Choose Relevant Items, and turn them into an array
$item_array = array(
'apple',
'banana',
'banana'
);

//implode items, turn into string
$item_implode = join("','", $item_array);

//declare an overall array for result
$product = array();

$productList = array();
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Name, Status as item_status from item_table where Name IN ('$item_implode') ORDER BY FIELD (Name, '$item_implode');");

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $x = 1;
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $product[$x]["Name"] = $row['Name'];
        $product[$x]["item_status"] = $row['item_status'];

        $x = $x + 1;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}


// test print all avaialable database values
for ($i=1; $i <= count($product); $i++) { 
    echo $product[$i]["Name"] . " - ";
    echo $product[$i]["item_status"] . "<br/>";
}
```

**With current code**, `$product[3]` (which I would like to be `banana`) **doesn't exist**, Since the code seems to remove duplicates automatically. **I don't want it to remove them.**

My motivation is that later in the code, I might want to display the same item in two variations, and when I display items I'm using a loop that is running on the items index number. therefore, the loop will have nothing to run on for any item that currently appears in my  `$item_array` more than once, unless the code will be changed so that it will get duplicates according to what I placed inside my array.

**EDIT:**

Updated working code:

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';

// Choose Relevant items, and turn them into an array
$item_array = array(
'apple',
'banana',
'carrot',
'banana',
'carrot',
'berry'
);

//implode items, turn into string
$item_implode = join("','", $item_array);

//declare an overall array for result
$product = array();

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Name, Status as item_status from item_table where Name IN ('$item_implode') ORDER BY FIELD (Name, '$item_implode');");

// New Code:

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


    $fruit_name = $row['Name'];
    // next you need to find all keys in $item_array which value is the fruit
    $keys = array_keys($item_array, $fruit_name);
    foreach ($keys as $key) {

        // add values for these keys
        $product[$key+1]['Name'] = $row['Name'];
        $product[$key+1]['item_status'] = $row['item_status'];

    }
}

/* REPLACED CODE: //////////////////////////

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $x = 1;
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $product[$x]["Name"] = $row['Name'];
        $product[$x]["item_status"] = $row['item_status'];

        $x = $x + 1;
    }
} 


else {
    echo "0 results";
}*/

/////////////////////////////////////////////

// test print all avaialable database values
for ($i=1; $i <= count($product); $i++) { 
    echo $product[$i]["Name"] . " - ";
    echo $product[$i]["item_status"] . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: `array_unique` before `join`?

Comment: @u_mulder You mean I should implement `array_unique` in the code? not sure how to do that from the example in the documentation. simply inserting it before join results in syntax error. Also, the docs says that `array_unique` is suppose to *remove* duplicates, while I want to *keep* duplicates.

Comment: there is an error in the sql above `SELECT Name, Status from item")"table` ~ a spurious `)`

Comment: yeah its just a typo though, ill fix it.

Comment: @RyanVincent I don't want to make it unique, I just want 2 variables/indexes to be created instead of one. both should be identical, as long as the index number is according to their order in my array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - there's no need to search for duplicate items. 
Your query currently is:

```
SELECT Name, Status from item)table where Name IN ('apple', 'banana', 'banana')
```

This is **redundant**

Do an `array_unique` while creating `$item_implode`:

```
$item_implode = join("','", array_unique($item_array));
```

This will leave `$item_array` untouched, but reduces your query.

Next, if I got you right you want one item from db for your query. This means that if you have several bananas in db only one record should be placed in `$product`. Okay, do this:

```
$founded_fruits = array();
// special array to track founded fruits
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $x = 1;
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // I suppose that `$row['Name']` is name of a fruit
        if (!in_array($row['Name'], $founded_fruits)) {
            $founded_fruits[] = $row['Name'];
            $product[$x]["Name"] = $row['Name'];
            $product[$x]["Status"] = $row['Status'];
        }

        $x = $x + 1;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

**Update**. SO okay - you want fruit occurrences in `products` to be equal it's occurrences in `$item_array`. Try this:

```
$product = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $fruit_name = $row['Name'];
    // next you need to find all keys in $item_array which value is the fruit
    $keys = array_keys($item_array, $fruit_name);
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        // add values for these keys
        $products[$key]['Name'] = $row['Name'];
        $products[$key]['item_status'] = $row['item_status'];
    }
}
```

Comment: I simplified my SELECT for the question, in reality I'm renaming fields (`Status as item_status`) , etc.

Comment: And no - I DO want duplicates. I clarified it in my first comment.

Comment: Want duplicates where?

Comment: Right now, `$product[2]` is `banana`. `$product[3]` doesn't exist since it's a duplicate, even though I placed it as the third entry in my array. I want `$product[3]` to be created *also*, and get its values for `banana`, just like `$product[2]`.

Comment: Well, okay looks like a get, wait a little.

Comment: I used your code with some modification as I wasn't sure how to apply it. Made little progress, but still facing 2 issues, Edited my question with new code in bottom.

Comment: Do you see that - `$products[$key]`? With `$key`, not with `$x`.

Comment: Thanks, ok, updated code again, now only issue is that first item is being skipped, why does it happen?

Comment: Sure you have `apple` in your table? Not `Apple` or `APPLE`?

Comment: yes. It doesn't depend on product name, even if I put another `banana` as first item, it will not get output

Comment: Check `$keys` values on each iteration. Cmpare to `$items_array` keys.

Comment: ok spotted problem: I'm echoing from $i=1, since in previous code I didn't want to create `[0]` index. With current code, first item is being created with `0` index. How do I get the first item to have `1` index as well?